# getStaticProps returns empty props object

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm trying to render a landing page using `getStaticProps` (Next.js) but it doesn't behave as expected. Here is my component:

```
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next'

const Brief = (props) => {

    console.log(JSON.stringify(props)) // returns an empty object
    return (
        <>
            {props[0]}
            {props[1]}
            {props[2]}
        </>
    )
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
    const WhatIUse = <div className="WhatIUse">What I use</div>

    const introduction = <div className="introduction">Introduction</div>

    const ContactInfo = <div className="ContactInfo">Where to find me</div>

    return {
        props: [introduction, WhatIUse, ContactInfo]
    }
}

export default Brief
```

The logging statement shows that `props` is returned as an empty object, what could be the issue?

Comment: Surely you must be getting an error when trying to run that?

Comment: Not at all, I am running a production build and no error messages are in the console, it's just that the elements don't show.

Comment: You should run a dev build to ensure you see all errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with that approach.

First, the variable `props` returned in `getStaticProps` must be an *object* containing values that are serializable as JSON. You're trying to pass an *array* which contains JSX elements (non-serializable).

Second, `getStaticProps` is used to fetch data for pre-rendering, you're not meant to generate JSX there, that'll be done in the component itself.

Here's a practical example based on your initial code:

```js
const Brief = (props) => {
    console.log(props) // Will log props passed in `getStaticProps`

    return (
        <>
            <div className="WhatIUse">{props.data[0]}</div>
            <div className="introduction">{props.data[1]}</div>
            <div className="ContactInfo">{props.data[2]}</div>
        </>
    )
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
    const WhatIUse = 'What I use'
    const introduction = 'Introduction'
    const ContactInfo = 'Where to find me'

    return {
        props: {
            data: [introduction, WhatIUse, ContactInfo]
        }
    }
}

export default Brief
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are using the function on a page file in fact, (files that are inside the 'pages' folder)

I had the same problem, but I was using the function in a component, which resulted in an empty object

When I started using it in a pages file, the function behaved as expected

Comment: that's it, is getStaticProps can only be exported from a page
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#only-allowed-in-a-page

I missed this from the doc and you gave the hint

Comment: Bro, u saved me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are calling the **getStaticProps** or **getServerSideProps** or **getStaticPaths** function from outside of pages or app directory (v-13). If you do that next js will send you an empty props object.
Next.js does not throw any error message to catch this error properly.